# Why my setState only work the first time in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

This is my code in imports and states declaration

```
import react, {useState,useEffect,useRef } from 'react'
import {getAll, getById,deleteById,patchTipo} from './_requests'
import ModalElimina from '../../modules/utils/ModalChElimina'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

import { KTSVG } from '../../../_metronic/helpers/components/KTSVG';
import { StringMappingType } from 'typescript';

type dataProps={
    fecha:string,
  }
    
  
const Data=(props:dataProps)=>{
    const Swal = require('sweetalert2')
    const [idUp,setIdUp]=useState<number>(0);
    const [nombre,setNombre]=useState("");
    const [estatus,setEstatus]=useState(true);
    

    const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
          cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
        },
        buttonsStyling: false
      })
    const [tiposAdicionales,setTiposAdicionales]=useState([] as any[]);    
    
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null)
    const deleteRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null)
```

And these are my functions

```
    async function actualizaActivo(id:number,estatusChange:boolean){
        try{
             const resp=await getById(id)  
             setIdUp(previd => id)
             setEstatus(prev=>estatusChange)
             setNombre(prev=>resp.data.snombre)
             mensajeActivo();
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
        
}


function mensajeActivo(){
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
        title: '¿Seguro que quieres cambiar el estatus?',
        text: "",
        icon: 'info',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Si, cambiar estatus!',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        reverseButtons: true
      }).then((result: { isConfirmed: any; dismiss: any; }) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            update()
        } else if (
          
          result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
        ) {
          
        }
      })   
}


    async function cargaDatosId(id:number){
        try{
             const resp=await getById(id)  
             setIdUp(previd => id)
             setEstatus(prev=>resp.data.bactivo)
             setNombre(prev=>resp.data.snombre)
             //await setIdUp(id)
             //await setEstatus(resp.data.bactivo)
             //await setNombre(resp.data.snombre)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
        
    }

    async function update(){
        try{
            const resp=await patchTipo(idUp,nombre,estatus)  
            console.log(resp)
            if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
                inputRef.current.click();
           }
           Swal.fire(
            'Actualizado correctamente',
            '',
            'success'
          )
            cargaDatos();
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
        
    }

    function eliminaSet(id:number){
        setIdUp(prev=>id)
        console.log(idUp)
    }

    async function elimina(){
        try{
             const response=await deleteById(idUp)  
             if (deleteRef && deleteRef.current) {
                deleteRef.current.click();
             }
             Swal.fire(
                'Eliminado correctamente',
                '',
                'success'
              )
             cargaDatos()
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
        
    }

   


    useEffect(()=>{
        cargaDatos();
      },[])
```

The problem is when I try to able or disable in the crud
I use the method actualizaActivo to set the information in the states
And later I use sweetalert2 to confirm the change
but doesn't work all the time
only in the second one

Comment: What's with the number tag beside useState? `const [idUp,setIdUp]=useState<number>(0);`

Comment: its only to declare the type, but its not important , i can delete that <number> and continue the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are calling all the setState and the functions in one 'render' of React so your state is not updated when you try to access it. It would be best to listen for state changes and then call `mensajeActivo`.

You can use useEffect like:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   if(idUp && nombre && estatus){
     mensajeActivo();
   }  
}, [idUp,nombre,estatus])
```